# Pass Gradient Color from one view controller to other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How to pass gradient color of collectionview cell background to other viewcontroller of custom view?

Comment: Is the "other" View Controller the ViewController of the CollectionView that holds the CollectionViewCell? Or is it some other VC?

Comment: is it parent view controller you want to pass the colors?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. Including some class names would be helpful.

Comment: Using notification center

Answer (score 0):

If the "other" ViewController you want to change the background gradient color is the one that holds you UICollectionView, then use the code below... If it is any other ViewController, you need to get the instance of the ViewController that you want to change...

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?

    func funcThatChangesColorInOtherViewColtroller() {
        let firstGradientColor = UIColor.red
        let secondGradientColor = UIColor.blue
        delegate?.viewControllerShouldUpdateBackgroundToColors(firstColor: firstGradientColor, secondColor: secondGradientColor)
    }

}

protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func viewControllerShouldUpdateBackgroundToColors(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor)
}

class OtherViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, MyCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self


        return cell
    }

    func viewControllerShouldUpdateBackgroundToColors(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor) {
        //Set your VCs Background Gradient to the Colors in
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a initialiser in your SecondViewController so you pass right there the color you may want before presenting it.

```
init(color: UIColor) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.color = color
}
```

Then when you instantiate your SecondViewController and use color inside of it.